# Bus Seat Arrangement with Numbers in chart - C# Algorithm - Find Seat is W, M, S from number is inputted

Tags: c#, data-structures

```
W  M  S     |   S  M  W

01 02 03    |   19 20 21

04 05 06    |   22 23 24

07 08 09    |   25 26 27

10 11 12    |   28 29 30

13 14 15    |   31 32 33

16 17 18    |   34 35 36
```

These are the seat arrangements for a bus. I have to write a C# algorithm - When user gives a number the algorithm should return the seat is W, M or S. Example - If user enters number 26 algorithm should return M. What will the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
public static char SeatId(int seatNumber)
{
    return seatNumber >= 19 
        ? "SMW"[(seatNumber-1) % 3]
        : "WMS"[(seatNumber-1) % 3];
}
```

Shorter but less readable:

```
public static char SeatId(int seatNumber)
{
    return --seatNumber >= 18 
        ? "SMW"[seatNumber % 3]
        : "WMS"[seatNumber % 3];
}
```